# Tenho uma automação feita em python mas não sei como uma pessoa qualquer consegue utilizar ela

Tags: python

Basicamente fiz uma automação para preencher formulários automaticamente, mas não sei como passar para um possível cliente e nem como ele vai fazer para usar (Sou Estagiário e Comecei com python a pouco tempo)